# My Ubuntu Server 12.04 box cannot ping my ADSL modem

Tags: networking, ping

My Ubuntu Server (12.04) box doesn't ping my ADSL modem.  I've setup a simple network which connects a XP box, a Ubuntu Server box and an ADSL modem.  The XP box pings the Ubuntu Server and the ADSL modem, but the Ubuntu Server pings only the XP box.  "Destination host unreachable" is reported whenever the Ubuntu Server pings the ADSL modem.

How should I tackle the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your Ubuntu firewall is causing the issue. Try switching it off, and see if that fixes the problem. The only other thing I can think of is to restart the modem, wait 5 minutes, restart the ubuntu machine, and see if that resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try making your ADSL as DHCP, or your DHCP on the Ubuntu Server is Causing problems with the DSL try disabling it or.... Disable the DHCP on the ADSL if that doesn't work give them static ip's and Gateway as ADSL IP...
Hope that will solve.>

Comment: These instructions are pretty unclear, to me. Can you please elaborate and spell out in greater detail what needs to be done to fix this issue. Thank.